# Applescript Error 5000 access to active directory

Tags: windows, macos, applescript, ntfs

I have a problem with an apple script because I try to access to a directory but his parent is hidden with NTFS rules. When i do this command:
mount volume ("smb://srv-data1/Apprenants/" & userName")
Apprenants is hidden
I have the error number -5000
Please can you help me I need some help and i didn't find any answer!
Thank's Killian Kaempf

Comment: You can use Terminal to get some meaning about errors. "macerror -5000" shows: "(afpAccessDenied): Insufficient access privileges for operation"

Answer (score 0):

did you try the "as user name" and "with password" parameters?

```
mount volume ("smb://srv-data1/Apprenants/" & userName") as user name "validusername" with password "validpassword"
```

Comment: Thanks. I have trying but the mac report to me I have not the required autorisation to accesss to the server.